# Declare dynamic range using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to declare a range the following way:

```
searchRow = 19
startCellCol = Worksheets("Production Tracking").Range("DV19").Column
endCellCol = Worksheets("Production Tracking").Range("H19").Column

Set rRng = Worksheets("Production Tracking").Range(Cells(19, endCellCol), Cells(19, startCellCol))
```

but I'm getting error 1004. If I remove the `Worksheets("Production Tracking")` it works, but in a wrong worksheet.

Is there a way of making this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a Worksheet named "Production Tracking"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
With Worksheets("Production Tracking")
    Set rRng = .Range(.Cells(19, endCellCol), .Cells(19, startCellCol))
End With
```

Otherwise you would have to write the `Worksheets(...)` infront of every `Range()` and `Cells()` to avoid this error